# search process using php and mysql not workingg

Tags: php, mysql

i have a search page with three types of search that allow user to use it 
by searching the newest member 
by searching according to the specialization
by entering the first name 
 and each query will display a different message and different results

the page display the default query only
but the 3 types  do not work can anyone help me ???

## member_search.php

```
  <?php
// connect to database 
 require_once('include/connect.php'); 
//default  message  on top of the result  display
$querySrting="WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date ASC ";
$queryMSG="Showing newest to oldest memebrs by default";
///IF STATMENT TO DISTINGOUICH SEARCHING
if(isset($_POST['listByq'])
{
  if($_POST['listByq']=="newest_members")
  {
      $querySrting="WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date DESC " or die(mysql_error());
      $queryMSG="Showing senior to oldest memebrs";
  }
elseif($_POST['listByq']=="by_specialization")

   {
      $querySrting="WHERE specialization! = '' ORDER BY user_id DESC" or die(mysql_error());
      $queryMSG="showing members with specs";
   }
elseif($_POST['listByq']=="by_firstname")
  {
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $fname = stripcslashes($fname);
      $fname = strip_tags($fname);
      $querySrting="WHERE  first_name LIKE '%$fname%'"or die(mysql_error());
      $queryMSG="Showing member with the name you searched for";
  }
}
///******query the member data using the queryString*******//
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date FROM user $querySrting") or die(mysql_error());
 //**********************outputlist*********************************//
 $outputlist="";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
     $id=$row['user_id'];
     $firstname=$row['first_name'];
     $lastname=$row['last_name'];
     $birthdate=$row['birth_date'];
     $registereddate=$row['registered_date']; 
     ////***********for the upload image*************************//
      $check_pic="members/$id/image01.jpg";
   $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
   if(file_exists($check_pic))
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
   }
   else
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
   }

   $outputlist.='
   <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="23%" rowspan="3"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                  <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                  <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$id.'" target="_blank">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                    <td>'.$birthdate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$registereddate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
          ';

 }//close while

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lam_El_Chamel</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
  <div class="img-border">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
      <div id="header">

        <div id="logo">
          <marquee width="80%" behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
            <h1><b>Social media</b></h1>
          </marquee>
        </div>

            <?php /*require_once('login.php')*/; ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#"><img src="images/web_header copy.jpg" width="1121" height="210" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="wide-content">


              <table width="94%" height="63">
                <tr>
                  <td width="29%"><form id="form1" method="post" action="member_search.php">

                  Browse Newest Members
                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="go" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="listbyq" value="newest_members" />
                  </form></td>
                  <td width="28%"><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="member_search.php">
                    Search By specialization
                    <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="go" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="listbyq" value="by_specialization" />
                  </form></td>
                  <td width="43%"><form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="member_search.php">
                    Search By firstname
                    <label>
                    <input type="text" name = "fname" id="fname" />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="go" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="listbyq" value="by_firstname" />
                  </form></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <br />
              <table width="70%" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <td><?php print "$queryMSG";  ?>
                         <br />
                      <?php print "$outputlist";  ?>
                   </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php /*require_once('footer.php');*/ ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="listbyq" value="newest_members" />
```

But your PHP is:

```
if($_POST['listByq']=="newest_members")
```

The fieldnames aren't matching, because the case isn't the same; the POST variable has a capitalized 'B'.

You just need to rename either the fields in the form or in the PHP so that both sets match.

Answer (score 0):

Your if conditions are wrong

```
if(isset($_POST['listByq'])=="newest_members")
```

change it to something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['listByq'])) {

 if ($_POST['listByq']=="newest_members") {

    $querySrting="WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date DESC " or die(mysql_error());
    $queryMSG="Showing senior to oldest memebrs";
 }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it give me that the { after the first if is wrong   see my question i will edit